# Eclipse - how to get multi-lines as a group in regex?

Tags: regex, eclipse, multiline

I am working on legacy codes. This question is limited on eclipse IDE(especially eclipse regex).
Some of code is not valid no more so I wish to edit those statements at once.

Here is the statement sample in a JSP.

```
<%! 
    int score = 100;
%>
<script for=window event=onload>
    doSomething();
    console.log("Your point is <%= score %>")
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is something like this.

- grep contents between script tags
- generate new script tag and put the contents inside of certain statement

Here is what I have done for it

- Search(default, Ctrl + H) `(<script).*(event).*(onload)(.*)(>)(.*)(</script>)`
- If it works(Unfortunately not working for now), the group number 6 will be the contents
- Replace regex with `<script> window.addEventListener('load', function(){ $6 }, false); </script>`

So the final form that I want is something like this.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        doSomething();
        console.log("Your point is <%= score %>")
    }, false);
</script>
```

I have tried to put `(?m)` very first of the searching regex, but I did not work.

How can I get the multi-line contents as a group with regex on eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression **replace all `.` with `[\s\S]` to handle multi-line** content and all `*` (greedy) with **`*?` (non-greedy)** to match only one `<script>` element instead everything from the first to the last `<script>` element (if a file contains more than one `<script>` element):

```
(<script)[\s\S]*?(event)[\s\S]*?(onload)([\s\S]*?)(>)([\s\S]*?)(</script>)
```

In the replacement string `\R` can be used for a line break:

```
<script>\R  window.addEventListener('load', function(){$6  }, false);\R</script>
```

Note: In Eclipse [regular expressions according the Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) can be used.